# Cordova info.plist The app's Info.plist file - NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription y NSCameraUsageDescription

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap

Hola tengo una app creada con cordova y phonegap y al momento de subir la app desde el xcode a la tienda, me llega un email con el siguiente texto:

> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code
>   references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
>   Info.plist file should contain a NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key
>   with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely
>   why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted
>   to the App Store that access user data are required to include a
>   purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may
>   reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not
>   use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact
>   the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version
>   of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more
>   (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).
>   ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code
>   references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
>   Info.plist file should contain a NSCameraUsageDescription key with a
>   user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your
>   app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the
>   App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose
>   string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference
>   APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these
>   APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the
>   developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of
>   their code that doesn't contain the APIs.

Acabo de editar el archivo **config.xml** añadiendo lo siguiente, pero el error persiste

```
<widget>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="*">
            <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="App would like to access the camera." />
            <variable name="MICROPHONE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="App would like to access the microphone." />
            <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="App would like to access the library." />
        </plugin>
</widget>
```

**app/platforms/ios/app/app-Info.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en_US</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Mi Aplicacion</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0.0</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string/>
    <key>NSMainNibFile~ipad</key>
    <string/>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Debes explicar el motivo por el que tu app necesita a acceder a las fotos, no simplemente decir que vas a acceder

Comment: Le tengo que cambiar el texto al value ?

Comment: Si, para explicarlo de cara al usuario

Comment: @Leemur hice los cambios e igual me la rechazaron

Comment: Igual no me he explicado bien. En el archivo Info.plist de tu App tienes que crear un campo llamado NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription y escribir el motivo de acceder el álbum de fotos, y otro campo llamado NSCameraUsageDescription y  escribir el motivo de acceder a la cámara

Comment: @Leemur agrege el codigo del info.plist, la configuracion anterior lo estaba haciendo en el config.xml, lo tengo que hacer en el info.plist ?

Answer (score 1):

Añade estos campos al código del info.plist:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>ESCRIBE AQUI TU TEXTO EXPLICANDO PORQUE ACCEDES A LA LIBRERIA DE FOTOS DE USUARIO</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>ESCRIBE AQUI TU TEXTO EXPLICANDO PORQUE ACCEDES A LA CAMARA DE FOTOS DE USUARIO</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

Según entiendo, si editas el info.plist luego de generar nuevamente la plataforma se borraran los cambios, yo lo tengo de la siguiente forma en el config.xml y funciona perfectamente:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="deployment-target" value="7.0" />
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <config-file parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
        <string>La Aplicación necesita permiso de la camara para tomar fotografias.</string>
    </config-file>
    <config-file parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
        <string>La Aplicación necesita permiso de la galería para obtener fotografias.</string>
    </config-file>
```

...
**OJO dependiendo del mensaje explicativo sobre el permiso, también pueden rechazar la APP, debido a que realmente no aclara el uso de la cámara o la galería**